# Not able to link dependent header files in cpp file for Rcpp

Tags: c, r, rcpp

Based on this tutorial - http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-callling-c-code-with-rcpp/
I was trying to call a C function from R.
The C code have following dependencies and it works perfectly after compiling the C code

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
```

Now when i am trying to load the so file , i am seeing the below error.

```
dyn.load("storage.so")
Error in dyn.load("storage.so") : 
unable to load shared object '/home/algotree/Rcode/storage.so':
/home/algotree/Rcode/storage.so: undefined symbol: json_object_array_length
```

Seems R is not able to link the rest of header files.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why does anybody wants to link headers today ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) (for which we also provide *ample* documentation regarding use on its own, in package, via inline, ...).

You seem to use JSON-parsing functionality, but apparently have not linked to a JSON-parser library corresponding  to the header `json/json.h` you included.

Apart from this question being incomplete in its code example and hence not reproducible, I see two issues here:

1. learn the ropes about C/C++ program using libraries, and
2. apply this to the R context.

As you using JSON and Curl based on your headers, you could (and probably should) study the corresponding packages like [RJSONIO](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RJSONIO) and [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RCurl).

If you know what is going there and understand the mechanics, you can then use [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) to provide the new functionality you are seeking. But just by throwing [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) in the mix, these issues do not address themselves. You need to understand how in include headers and link libraries.

Comment: Can you point me to a example where they have linked an external library to the RCpp. am clueless on linking libraries in such contexts.

Comment: See the Rcpp page on CRAN and the 90+ packages using it. Pick one that uses an external library. And/or read the **vignette we specifically wrote for this** : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf

Comment: I found some packages uses their own personalized header file preserved in inst/headers folder. And i could figure out that these are linked using PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include in makevar file. But then its not working when i gave a additional PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/lib to that option. I am totally new to these linking. Kindly provide me more pointers.

Comment: You are abusing the kindness of strangers here.  The project is four years old. I have helped dozens of people *with the very question* on the mailing list, on SO and on other places.  Please do some research rather than to expect me to retype it all for you.

Comment: my apologies. I will try with your  RJSONIO and RCurl options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved the issue , for running the code  i had to add -lcurl and -ljson as command link arguement. So the command  R CMD SHLIB should have executed is the below commands

g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include  -I/usr/include/   -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c storage.cpp -o storage.o
g++ -shared -o storage.so storage.o -L/usr/lib  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lcurl -ljson  -lR

This can be done by editing the PKG_LIBS flags.